# Forward questions to an email account?

Tags: support, email

How do I get a weekly digest of Stack Overflow SAS questions forwarded to my Gmail account?

If this is not possible, how do I get individual messages forwarded to my Gmail account?

Answer (score 5):

What you need to do is to go to your profile page, https://stackoverflow.com/users/4660209/roger-deangelis , and then select Edit Profile and Settings, then select Preferences.

Make sure your email address is in the box "send notification emails to...", and then click on "Manage filtered questions emails".

You can either click on "Favorite tags" if you've already favorited the SAS tag, or "New filter".  If you do the latter, then select "Just the ... tag", enter SAS there, click Add Rule.  (Make sure it doesn't end up "sass").  You can add a few others, like

- sas-iml
- sas-macro
- sas-ods
- sas-gtl
- proc-sql
- enterprise-guide

All of which are SAS related.

If you just want StackOverflow, select Just the ... site.  Otherwise use all sites, as you might get questions on CrossValidated for example also.

Then make sure on 3. to select the email address you want email updates sent to (check "Yes"), and how often you want them.

There you go, you're going to get a digest every (frequency you ask for)!

Here's a picture of the final page:
[image]